# Data table 'All' selection, "Showing 1 to 0 of 100 entries"

Tags: java, jquery, datatables

I have a tabbed data table and I'd like to add the selection of 'All' to my menu length.

I have 10, 25, 50, 75 which all work fine, but the 'All' option returns "Showing 1 to 0 of 100 entries"... In firebug I can see for the selection 'All' aaData is empty. Am I missing a specific parameter? Thanks.

JS:

```
`$('#datatable').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[0, 'asc']],
    "sDom": '<"H"lr>t<"F"ip>', // Specifies where to inject controls
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
   "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 75, -1], [10, 25, 50, 75, "All"]],
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": 'datatable.json',
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        {
            "fnRender": function(oObj, sVal) {
                return '<a class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" title="Edit" href="oObj.aData[0]">Edit</a>';
            },
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [2]
        }
    ],        
    /* The following lines are used to send extra data to the server */
    "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function(json) {
            fnCallback(json);
        });
    }
}).columnFilter({aoColumns: [{type: "text"}, {type: "text"}]});`
```

JSON:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "datatable.json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Page getDataTablePage(
        @RequestParam int sEcho,
        @RequestParam int iColumns,
        @RequestParam int iSortCol_0,
        @RequestParam String sSortDir_0,
        @RequestParam String sSearch_0,
        @RequestParam String sSearch_1,
        @RequestParam int iDisplayStart,
        @RequestParam int iDisplayLength) {
    logger.info("Inside " + ((StackTraceElement[]) Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace())[1]);
    Integer total = service.getCount();
    Integer totalMatching = service.getCountBySearch(sSearch_0, sSearch_1);       
    List<Data> rowData = service.getPage(iDisplayStart, iDisplayLength, iSortCol_0, sSortDir_0,
            sSearch_0, sSearch_1);
    Page p = new Page();
    p.setsEcho(sEcho);
    p.setiTotalRecords(total);
    p.setiTotalDisplayRecords(totalMatching);
    // Convert list of unordered hashmaps into 2D array for DataTables
    String[][] pageData = new String[rowData.size()][iColumns];
    // For each row
    for (int r = 0; r < rowData.size(); r++) {
        Data d = rowData.get(r);
        pageData[r][0] = d.getItem1();
        pageData[r][1] = d.getItem2();
    }
    p.setaaData(pageData);
    logger.info("p=" + p);
    return p;
}
```

myBatis

```
<select id = "getPage" parameterType="map" resultType="com.ti.ds.psi.domain.Data">
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT rownum rn, s.* FROM (
    SELECT item1, item2
    FROM items
    WHERE upper(item1) like '%'||upper(#{sSearch_0})||'%'
    AND upper(item2) like '%'||upper(#{sSearch_1})||'%'
    ORDER BY
    <choose>
        <when test="sidx==0">item1</when>
        <when test="sidx==1">item2</when>
    </choose>
    ${sord}
    ) s
    )
    WHERE rn BETWEEN #{start} AND #{start} + #{rows}
</select>
```

Comment: we need more information to answer your question

Comment: sorry, hit enter before I finished

Comment: why do you give parameter "aLengthMenu" instead of "lengthMenu"?

Comment: When you click all doesnt the request get sent with `iDisplayLength=-1`? How do you handle this in `service.getPage`?

Comment: @CarlosCalla using lengthMenu in place of aLengthMenu only shows the default selections

Comment: @Danny yes it does.. I'm returning the page, including the number of rows which is reading the data through sql from my dao.xml. I believe it has to do with with my sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.. I added a simple piece to my query-- 'OR #{rows} = -1'.

'rows' are defined as my table length.

Thanks.